# CakePHP 3 DateTime Validation Iso 8601 with timezone

Tags: validation, datetime, cakephp

I'm trying to validate a date in cakePHP 3 (3.3.13). The data I recieve is in ISO 8601 format with timezone, like 2017-02-17T23:00:00.000Z .

I have a simple `$validator->date()` rule, which always fails to validate the date. I tried using my own Validation Provider, in which I build a Chronos object out of the provided value. As Chronos is using the DateTimeInterface the validation succeds, but I recieve an SQL error:

`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-02-17T23:00:00.000Z' for column 'launchdate' at row 1`

This is my bootstrap.php:

```
require __DIR__ . '/paths.php';
require ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';
require CORE_PATH . 'config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php';

use Cake\Cache\Cache;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleErrorHandler;
use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\Configure\Engine\PhpConfig;
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Error\ErrorHandler;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Network\Email\Email;
use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFactory;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;
use Cake\Utility\Security;

try {
    Configure::config('default', new PhpConfig());
    Configure::load('app', 'default', false);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage() . "\n");
}
if (!Configure::read('debug')) {
    Configure::write('Cache._cake_model_.duration', '+1 years');
    Configure::write('Cache._cake_core_.duration', '+1 years');
}
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
mb_internal_encoding(Configure::read('App.encoding'));
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en_US');
$isCli = php_sapi_name() === 'cli';
if ($isCli) {
    (new ConsoleErrorHandler(Configure::consume('Error')))->register();
} else {
    (new ErrorHandler(Configure::consume('Error')))->register();
}
if ($isCli) {
    require __DIR__ . '/bootstrap_cli.php';
}
if (!Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl')) {
    $s = null;
    if (env('HTTPS')) {
        $s = 's';
    }
    $httpHost = env('HTTP_HOST');
    if (isset($httpHost)) {
        Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http' . $s . '://' .      $httpHost);
    }
    unset($httpHost, $s);
}
Cache::config(Configure::consume('Cache'));
ConnectionManager::config(Configure::consume('Datasources'));
Email::configTransport(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));
Email::config(Configure::consume('Email'));
Log::config(Configure::consume('Log'));
Security::salt(Configure::consume('Security.salt'));
Log::config('default', [
    'engine' => 'Syslog'
]);
Request::addDetector('mobile', function ($request) {
    $detector = new \Detection\MobileDetect();
    return $detector->isMobile();
});
Request::addDetector('tablet', function ($request) {
    $detector = new \Detection\MobileDetect();
    return $detector->isTablet();
});
Plugin::load('Muffin/Footprint');
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
DispatcherFactory::add('Asset');
DispatcherFactory::add('Routing');
DispatcherFactory::add('ControllerFactory');`
```

I always thought, that a datetime field will be patched to a Chronos / DateTime object in patchEntity(). Am I wrong here? Are there any Best Practices? 
I haven't modified the bootstrap.php in any way regarding date formats. Thank you!

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using, things do change now and then. Also please show what's actually in your bootstrap, as again, things do change over time, especially the app templates default date/time configuration has been changed quite a few times.

Comment: My cake version is 3.3.13 . The bootstrap.php hasn't been modified.

Comment: Again, the the app templates bootstrap has been changed over time, so saying that you haven't modified it, doesn't really help, as no one can tell what version of it you're using (the app template and the CakePHP framework are two different repositories).

Comment: Oha, sorry my project wasn't build with the cakePHP skeleton app project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't changed the default configuration of the `datetime` database type, which requires the input to be in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. When encountering a different format, the type class will return the input value as is, ie it's not being marshalled.

If you need your dates to be accepted in a different format, you can for example configure the existing `datetime` type in order for this to apply to mashalling globally (ie to all columns that are of type `DATETIME/TIMESTAMP`):

```
\Cake\Database\Type::build('datetime')
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

If you'd wanted this to apply to only a specific model/column, then you could create and use a custom type (simply extending `\Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType` would be enough) instead of `datetime`, and apply it to your models schema where you need it:

```
// in src/Database/Type/CustomDateTimeType.php

namespace App\Database\Type;

use Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType;

class CustomDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
}
```

```
// in the respective table class

protected function _initializeSchema(\Cake\Database\Schema\Table $schema)
{
    // ...
    $schema->columnType('launchdate', 'customDateTime');
    return $schema;
}
```

```
// in config/bootstrap.php

use Cake\Database\Type;

Type::map('customDateTime', 'App\Database\Type\CustomDateTimeType');
Type::build('customDateTime')
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Parsing Localized Datetime Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-datetime-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Adding Custom Types](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)**

Comment: Great ! You always explain well.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I had to change the format to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" to get it converted to the correct value for the Database. But it still won't go through the datetime() validator.

Comment: @Seb Changing the format like that should not be required, unless you'd wanted to only accept dates with a `Z` timezone, as what you're doing there will hardcode the timezone identifier to `Z`. Marshalling and validation are two separate processes, with such a format, you'll need a custom validation rule, respectively a custom `datetime` validator regex pattern: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896273/cakephp-3-parse-date-with-localstringformat-to-correct-sql-format-and-correct/34896974#34896974**